# Exporting GeoJSON from Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

I am trying to export coordinates of way that I found.

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/17Ne

But when I click export/ as GeoJSON I don't get coordinates in downloaded file.

How can I do this?

Even though map is empty on overpass webpage, there are coordinates in Data sheet

Comment: Are you clicking the 'Data' tab on the far right? coordinates are LineString       [18.9260178, 42.3767789],  [18.9287158, 42.3772670], etc.

Answer (score 4):

Change your query. See https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/17Ng

Then, you can export/ download as GEOJSON

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way(167047843);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can also use this command line utility

```
npm install -g query-overpass
```

and then

```
echo "[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way(167047843);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
" | query-overpass > way_167047843.geojson
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need coordinates in [lat,lon] format, not in node format. I resolved problem by exporting as raw OSM data.

Comment: FYI, GeoJSON spec expects `[lon, lat]` order, not `[lat,lon]`

Comment: The export from the query above is a valid GeoJSON file that contains the selected way as a polygon. What do you mean by "node format"?

Answer (score 4):

`[out:json]` produces JSON, not GeoJSON. This is also stated in the documentation [Overpass QL, section Output Format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out:.29).

You can convert raw OSM data to GeoJSON by using [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson). This is also done by Overpass turbo as stated at [Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON).